# Whats App Web QR Scanner damaged?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I got a problem with my WhatsApp QR Code Scanner:
[image]

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Resurrection Remix Rom (Nightly with Marshmallow) and WhatsApp 2.12.479.
Starting the "normal" camera and using it is no problem. It works fine.
All I could find with google are problems regarding a flipped scanner, but as you can see that is not my problem :/.

I already reinstalled WhatsAPP, but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

after hours of searchng I found a post where a suggestion was just to hold the scanner on the qr code... It worked..

So nothing to do here ;)